# Blender sapling mesh leaves rotation

Tags: sapling-addon

[image: tree with custom leaves]

Hey guys,

I was hoping to get some help with the leaf rotation with the sapling plugin. I'm finding that a custom leaf mesh seems to always orientate relative to the scene and not the branch direction.

In the image attached you can see the default dupliface option with the custom leaf mesh. In this example the leaves on the left are pointing correctly away out from the tree, whereas on the right the leaf seems to be incorrectly folded back. If you remove the random rotation all leaves obviously orientate with the exact same rotation in the z axis.

I wasn't sure if it is something I have missed, but any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Think I will emulate and go into particle settings and see if I can do something...

Comment: Thanks for the reply ZargulTheWizard. I tired particles, but was encountering similar issues, which I believe are related to the 3d Cursor issue shown below. There are definite benefits to the particle method, but for the moment I want to see how accurate I can get the leaf position/representation to something that you'd get from GrowFX. Might be for later down the track.

Comment: I had meant that I was going to go and check it out, but hey, looks like daniel's got something :-D Au revior!

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution/user error, at least I think for now...

[image]

The 3d cursor [image] had rotational transform which was having an influence on the rotation of the pivot of the sapling tree when it was created.

Just make sure next time you come across funky leaf rotations....

1.Under the view tab for the viewport, make sure to zero all rotation to the 3D cursor.
[image]