# Make leaves head to branch direction (sapling addon)

Tags: sapling-addon

I am trying to generate something with the sapling addon where the leaves (custom object from the screne in my case) are looking at the direction of the end of a branch. Seems what ever I try they are rotating all over the place.

I tried to play with the rotation of the leaves etc but I cannot make it work.

Here I marked with the arrows how those leaf objects should be directed.

[image]

In this one it is mentioned that the 3D cursor rotation set to 0 solved the problem but I already have that set to 0:

[Blender sapling mesh leaves rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208935/blender-sapling-mesh-leaves-rotation)

Is this even possible with the sapling addon? Or are there any other good addons which can do this?

Comment: Hello, I have a relevant answer here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/241663/110840

Comment: To make this process easier, consider generating a tree with less geometry, hand-making a few branches with correct UVs and distributing those with a particle system first.  Apply that system and then separate those to another object for your final leaf particle system.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways, 1st sapling generator itself includes leaves objects but I am not sure if you can use custom object for it. Another way with object like yours that is not way too complicated, you can go and select 1 vert at the end of every branch, make vertex group and assign those vertices into that group

Now go to particles settings, set Density to your vertex group and don't forget you need these two settings as well: (they are visible only if you check **Advanced**

[image]

Now you can end up with something like this what is exactly what you want (I used only some random object, you will use your leaves.

[image]

Comment: In the sapling leaves settings I selected the DupliVerts and I could select my custom leaf object, that is how I created that above. It is just that I could not make it so the leaf direction is pointing where the branch is pointing. Before you selected the verts at the end of the branch did you convert the sapling curve to a mesh?

Comment: yes you have to convert it into mesh in order to use particle settings

Comment: Okay, and did you make any specific changes when selecting your object as a custom object? I went to Render -> Render As: Object, and selected my custom object in the Instance Object but it won't display it. If I change it back to path it displays the paths.

Comment: @MikoCG personally whenever I used sapling I wasn't happy with their leaves, but maybe I could make it work nowadays